# In a one dimensional numpy array of 1's and 0's, how can I convert the next n elements following a 1 to 0's?

Tags: python, numpy, vectorization, numpy-ndarray, masked-array

For a one dimensional numpy array of 1's and 0's, how can I effectively "mask" the array such that after the occurrence of a 1, the next n elements of the array are converted to zero. After the n elements have passed, the pattern repeats such that the first next occurrence of a 1 is preserved followed again by n zeros.

It is important that the **first eligible** occurrences of 1 are preserved, so a simple mask such as:
[true, false, false, true ...] won't work.
furthermore, the data set is massive so efficiency is important.

I've written crude python code to give me the desired results, but it is way too slow for what I need.
Here is an example:

```
data = [0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1]
n = 3

newData = []
tail = 0
for x in data:
    if x == 1 and tail <= 0:
        newData.append(1)
        tail = n
    else:
        newData.append(0)
        tail -= 1
print(newData)
```

newData: [0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1]

Is there possibly a vectorized numpy solution to this problem?
I'm processing tens of thousands of arrays, with more than a million elements in each array. So far using numpy functions has been the only way to manage this.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, there is no option completely in numpy to do this. You could still use numpy to reduce the time for grabbing the indices, though.

```
data = [0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1]
n=3
def get_new_data(data,n):
  new_data = np.zeros(len(data))
  non_zero = np.argwhere(data).ravel()
  idx = non_zero[0]
  new_data[idx] =1
  idx += n
  for i in non_zero[1:]:
    if i > idx:
      new_data[i] = 1
      idx+=n
  return new_data
get_new_data(data, n)
```

A function like this should give you a better run time since you are not looping over the whole array.

If this is still not optimal to you, you can look at using [numba](https://numba.readthedocs.io/en/stable/user/5minguide.html), which works very well with numpy and is relatively easy to use.

Comment: This is way simpler and I see very minimal data write operations. Was headed in the same direction +1

Answer (score 0):

You could do it like this:-

```
N = 3
data = [0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1]
newData = data.copy()
i = 0
M = [0 for _ in range(N)]
while i < len(newData) - N:
    if newData[i] == 1:
        newData[i + 1:i + 1 + N] = M
        i += N
    i += 1

print(newData)
```

Comment: This is more efficient than my code, but I'm hoping there's a vectorized numpy solution to my problem that would be exponentially faster

Comment: @ArnoBooysen How could it possibly be *exponentially* faster?

Comment: @KellyBundy As in the exponential time saving relative to array size that you see when using vectorized numpy functions as opposed to iterating over the array. I assume that time taken for vectorized functions don't increase linearly with array size like iterating would?

Comment: My solution is actually quite fast. I wrapped the code into a function and, using time.perf_counter() to note the start and end of one million iterations, I found that it took ~1.7 seconds. Do you need it to be faster than 1.7E-6 per iteration?

Comment: @ArnoBooysen How would time for vectorized functions not increase linearly?

Comment: @DarkKnight How long does it take for "tens of thousands of arrays, with more than a million elements in each array" (as the updated question says)?

Comment: @KellyBundy If you run a vectorized function on an array of 10 000 elements, and again on 1 million, you'll see it's takes less than ten times as long even though the array is ten times larger. Maybe it's insignificant. Either way, numpy functions can be hundreds of times faster than using a loop in python

Comment: @ArnoBooysen That's likely still linear, though, for example 3n+2000.

Comment: @ArnoBooysen In other words, you seem to confuse linear with proportional. In any case, yes, something like "hundreds of times faster" sounds right and I'd like to see it here (hence my upvote of the question :-)

Comment: @KellyBundy I am more than happy to carry out a timing test if the OP could provide me with relevant sample data. Of course, if there are built-in functions that can be proven to achieve the OP's objective, I'd love to hear about them